# Is there a variable that return me the total size of the scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html

I need to get the max number of pixel that scrolled in the page.

I've tried window.pageXOffset but it return the atual scrolled , I need the full size always

Comment: Size of the scrollbar or height of the page?

Comment: the maximum ammout that the scrollbar can slide in pixels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to this [link](https://javascript.info/size-and-scroll-window#width-height-of-the-document)

**EDIT:** Congratulation you have solve it. I have include more example for you.

```js
let scrollLength = document.documentElement.scrollWidth-document.documentElement.clientWidth
myFunction();
window.addEventListener('scroll', myFunction);
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Pos: "+window.pageXOffset+"/"+scrollLength;
}
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  width: 1000px;
  color: lightgray;
}
#demo{
  color: black;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  }
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<a id="demo">xxx</a>
```

Comment: it return the size of the screen ,I need the maximum ammout that the scrollbar can slide in pixels

Comment: with window.pageXOffset if I scroll the page until the final , i got 17px ,I whant this number even if i did not scrolled the page

Comment: You have solve it before I have add your some example

Answer (score 0):

I just solve this using

document.documentElement.scrollWidth - document.documentElement.clientWidth;